# extracting first digit of a float64 variable

Tags: python, pandas, string

I imported a `.xlsb` file into python (pycharm IDE) by using `pd.read_excel()` function; however, before importing the `.xlsb` file, I convert it into `.xlsx` format and then import it. Please note that I did not use `.xlsb` because I faced issues regarding the parsing of the date variable.

Now I need to extract the first digit of a float64 type variable and I run the following code -

```
app_invoice = app_invoice \
    .assign (FIRSTDIGIT = int(str(app_invoice['INVOICE_AMOUNT'][:1]))
            )
```

But it does not extract the first digit. Then I just checked the issue by running the following code -

```
str(app_invoice['INVOICE_AMOUNT'])
```

but the output of it looks like this. I do not why it is `\n1` and so on

````
0         13611.34\n1         91000.00\n2           159.97\n3          1300.00\n4  
```
````

Comment: you mean "the first amount", not digit, I guess. What's the `type(app_invoice['INVOICE_AMOUNT'])` ?

Comment: not first amount, first digit from each amount. The type is -`<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>`

Comment: It doesn't look like pandas supports running `str` across a series of items; so you're just getting the result of `str` on the series itself, which is newline-separated pairs of whitespace-separated (index, value) pairs.

Comment: @Sharif, post `app_invoice['INVOICE_AMOUNT'].values`

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest for `app_invoice['INVOICE_AMOUNT'].values` I got this -`array([1.361134e+04, 9.100000e+04, 1.599700e+02, ..., 6.369000e+01,
       5.100000e+02, 4.872000e+03])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `Series.apply` explicitly.

```
first_digits = invoice['INVOICE_AMOUNT'].apply(lambda x: str(x)[:1])
```

that gets you a regular Python list of the digits; you can do something similar to turn it into a pandas column instead.

Answer (score 1):

Use `.astype(str)` to convert the float to a string, then use `.str.get(0)` to get the first character of this string.

```
app_invoice['INVOICE_AMOUNT'].astype(str).str.get(0)
```

This will return a pandas series of the first digits.